# Load & Save RTF FlowDocument

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf, flowdocument

We are using a RichTextBox (FlowDocument) in our application. User can enter & paste text and hyperlinks. The content of this FlowDocument could be loaded and saved. We need to save the content in Rtf format in order to be able to use it in other technologies e.g. Java. All works fine except if the FlowDocument contains a Hyperlink with an umlaut in the NavigateUri. From my point of view already the saved/generated Rtf text is corrupt/wrong. If we try to load this it ends in a crash.

Please find in the following a simple and reduced sample that demonstrates the crash. Just clicking on the button ends in the crash.

```
    <DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Click="SaveAndLoadClick">Save and Load</Button>
    <RichTextBox IsDocumentEnabled="True" Name="richTextBox">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Hyperlink Foreground="#FF0066CC" NavigateUri="http://www.öffnen.de" TextDecorations="Underline">www.öffnen.de</Hyperlink>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Corresponding code behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static void SetRtfText(FlowDocument document, string rtfText) {
        var textRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rtfText)))
            textRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }

    private static string GetRtfText(FlowDocument document) {
        var textRange = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            textRange.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
            stream.Position = 0;
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void SaveAndLoadClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var text = GetRtfText(richTextBox.Document);
        SetRtfText(richTextBox.Document, text);
    }
}
```

From my point of view the problem is the created Rtf text. Please see the following extract:

```
{\field{\*\fldinst { HYPERLINK "http://www.'f6ffnen.de" }}{\fldrslt {www.\'f6ffnen.de}}}}
```

The displayed text is escaped and okay. But the Url is not okay. As soon as the Rtf text is loaded a XamParseException is raised. The inner exception is an UriFormatException with in invalid Uri because the host name could not be resolved.

I already did a web research and was not able to find any potential solutions. For instance WordPad is working fine and creates correct Rtf text.

Sure I can parse the Rtf for hyperlinks and try to correct the link myself (with all the challenges). I debugged the code down into the corresponding Microsoft classes and from my point of the issues is related there.

Is there an easy way to solve this? Did I miss anything?

Thanks for any ideas, hints...
Torsten

Comment: have you tried to change the default encoding...?

Comment: This may be a bug in the built-in WPF control. I created a sample program with a 3rd party control (DevExpress), I created the hyperlink, saved the document and reloaded it without a problem. The hyperlink works. And the saved document opens in Wordpad with no problem.

Comment: @Frenchy Yes, I already tried to change the encoding but this does not solve the issue.

Comment: @JimFoye That was my assumption too. The FlowDocument is "quite old" and so I'm wondering that no one else stumbled over this. Might be that only few people affected by umlaut issues in hyperlinks in FlowDocuments